# Rewrite the Oracle SQL Query

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using Oracle DB and wrote a query with self join to fetch some data. The table is very large and the query is running for a long time and there is no scope to add index. The value for the records is in SELECT and in WHERE condition. I was advised to modify the query by removing the value from WHERE condition, by resulting in same output. Can someone share your thoughts?

```
select a.xid, a.sIdentifier
from    tbllarge a
        inner join tbllarge b on a.xid = b.xid
where   a.sIdentifier ='A1'
```

Comment: Schema modification is not allowed by the admin, in the environment I'm executing the query

Comment: What's the point of the `JOIN`?

Comment: Is `XID` either the primary key or a unique key on `TBLLARGE`?

Comment: @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica . Yes, XID is the primary key

Comment: @Nick For example, we need details about an employee and his manager where both employee and manager ID resides in the same table.

Comment: The query you have posted gets no information from the self-joined table. Without seeing something more closely approximating the real query (and ideally table structure as well) it's impossible to offer advice on how to optimise it. As it stands there is no reason to do a `JOIN` at all (hence the answer you have received).

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite the query as

```
SELECT XID, SIDENTIFIER
  FROM TBLLARGE
  WHERE SIDENTIFIER = 'A1'
```

`XID` is the primary key on the table so the self-join just joined rows to themselves, which doesn't really do anything important. Skip the self-join and your query will run faster, although without an index on `SIDENTIFIER` I doubt it will run particularly quickly.

Comment: If `XID` is the primary key, then Oracle should be able to [eliminate this unnecessary self-join](https://blog.jooq.org/2017/09/28/10-cool-sql-optimisations-that-do-not-depend-on-the-cost-model/#top9)

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a curious query:

```
select a.xid, a.sIdentifier
from tbllarge a join
     tbllarge b
     on a.xid = b.xid
where a.sIdentifier = 'A1'
```

I would interpret it as:

```
select a.*
from tbllarge a
where a.sIdentifier = 'A1' and
      exists (select 1 from tbllarge b where a.xid = b.xid);
```

For either query, you want two indexes:  `(sIdentifier, xid)` and `(xid)`.  If `xid` is the primary key, then that index already exists.